# How can I pull rows that match an exact string of characters, but that is buried within a larger string?

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I need to filter out rows in a data frame that contain this exact string "S[Phospho(STY)]Q". However, in every case this string is in the middle of a larger string, never at the beginning and never at the end.

The problem that I'm running into is that in the list below **I want my code to pull out QGS[Phospho(STY)]QAG and GS[Phospho(STY)]QP** but the str_detect function is only pulling rows that have additional letters contained in the string that is only a partial match like SSQGS[Phospho(STY)]**DDE**Q.

I tried adding \bS[phospho(STY)]Q\b but then nothing is filtered

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Reproducible example:

```
`col <- c("QGS[Phospho(STY)]QAG",
    "GS[Phospho(STY)]QP",
    "SSQGS[Phospho(STY)]DDEQ",
    "SSQGS[Phospho(STY)]DDEQI",
    "S[Phospho(STY)]TSSQPE")

dat <- data.frame(col)

STQ_dat <- dat %>%  
  filter(str_detect(col, "S[phospho(STY)]Q"))

STQ_dat`
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to account for the proper case of the letters you are looking for, i.e. use `P` instead of `p`. Second, by default the `pattern=` provided to `str_detect` is interpreted as a regular expression and both `[` and `]` (as well as `(` and `)`) are special characters in a regex, i.e. you have to escape them using `\\`, i.e. `\\[` to look for `[`. The way you used `[]` you specified a set of valid symbols, e.g. a string containing `SSQ` will match your pattern as the middle `S` matches a letter in the specified set.  A second option to avoid escaping would be to wrap the pattern in `fixed()`:

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

dat %>%
  filter(
    str_detect(col, "S\\[Phospho\\(STY\\)\\]Q")
  )
#>                    col
#> 1 QGS[Phospho(STY)]QAG
#> 2   GS[Phospho(STY)]QP

dat %>%
  filter(
    str_detect(col, fixed("S[Phospho(STY)]Q"))
  )
#>                    col
#> 1 QGS[Phospho(STY)]QAG
#> 2   GS[Phospho(STY)]QP
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be achieved with `grep()` in base R as well:

```r
dat = data.frame(col = c("QGS[Phospho(STY)]QAG",
                         "GS[Phospho(STY)]QP",
                         "SSQGS[Phospho(STY)]DDEQ",
                         "SSQGS[Phospho(STY)]DDEQI",
                         "S[Phospho(STY)]TSSQPE"), 
                 sth = 1:5)

dat[grep("QGS\\[Phospho\\(STY\\)\\]QAG|GS\\[Phospho\\(STY\\)\\]QP", dat$col), ]
#>                    col sth
#> 1 QGS[Phospho(STY)]QAG   1
#> 2   GS[Phospho(STY)]QP   2
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>